# Issue with writing a Unit Test for HttpContext.Current.Session

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq, mstest

I have a working application for which I need to now add a full set of unit tests. The current code stores the user information as follows:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["UserInfo"] = userData;
```

I'm using **moq** for my testing, and my unit test has the following code:

```
var server = new Mock<HttpServerUtilityBase>(MockBehavior.Loose);
var response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>(MockBehavior.Strict);
var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>(MockBehavior.Strict);

var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();

context.SetupGet(x => x.Request).Returns(request.Object);
context.SetupGet(x => x.Response).Returns(response.Object);
context.SetupGet(x => x.Server).Returns(server.Object);

var controller = new LoginController();

controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(
    context.Object, 
    new RouteData(), 
    controller);

JsonResult result = controller.LoginUser(
    new LoginHelper { 
        userName = "myusername", 
        password = "invalidpassword" 
        }
    ) as JsonResult;
```

Of course when I get to where the login process tries to create the session data, I get an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error becuase HttpContext.Current is null.

Some research has shown me that using Current isn't exactly compatible with MSTest, so I understand that I might need to change the way I store/load my user information. However, I would like some advice on which way to go here.

I would appreciate any suggestions on either how to get my unit tests to work, or a different method to store the user info to make it more compatible with unit tests.

Comment: It is strange to use `HttpContext.Current` in ASP.Net MVC app, but you can simply set `HttpContext.Current` to you mock context (creating such context is whole another story so :) )... You really should look into using MVC way of accessing context or wrapping whole session into interface and taking dependency on that instead of direct access to `HttpContext.Current`.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov If it's strange to use HttpContext.Current, what is the alternative?

Comment: http://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+access+httpcontext+from+controller+mvc give good results.

Comment: An alternative would be to inject a SessionStateBase into the controller, rather than getting it from the HttpContext.

Answer (score 4):

This was the solution I came up with. It is a combination of a few things I found in various places including here:

First, I created 2 classes .. MockHttpSession, and MockHelpers

```
public class MockHttpSession : HttpSessionStateBase
{
    Dictionary<string, object> m_SessionStorage = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public override object this[string name]
    {
        get { return m_SessionStorage[name]; }
        set { m_SessionStorage[name] = value; }
    }

    public override void Abandon()
    {
        // Do nothing
    }
}

public class MockHelpers
{
    public static HttpContext FakeHttpContext()
    {
        var httpRequest = new HttpRequest("", "http://localhost/", "");
        var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        var httpResponse = new HttpResponse(stringWriter);
        var httpContext = new HttpContext(httpRequest, httpResponse);

        var sessionContainer = new HttpSessionStateContainer(
            "id", 
            new SessionStateItemCollection(),
            new HttpStaticObjectsCollection(), 
            10, 
            true,
            HttpCookieMode.AutoDetect,
            SessionStateMode.InProc, 
            false);

        SessionStateUtility.AddHttpSessionStateToContext(httpContext, sessionContainer);

        return httpContext;
    }
}
```

Then I changed my unit test code to use these:

```
var server = new Mock<HttpServerUtilityBase>(MockBehavior.Loose);
var response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>(MockBehavior.Strict);
var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>(MockBehavior.Strict);
var session = new MockHttpSession();

var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
context.SetupGet(x => x.Request).Returns(request.Object);
context.SetupGet(x => x.Response).Returns(response.Object);
context.SetupGet(x => x.Server).Returns(server.Object);
context.SetupGet(x => x.Session).Returns(session);

HttpContext.Current = MockHelpers.FakeHttpContext();

var controller = new LoginController();
controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(context.Object, new RouteData(), controller);

JsonResult result = controller.LoginUser(new LoginHelper { userName = "MyUserName", password = ""InvalidPassword }) as JsonResult;
```

This was able to successfully test the code with both valid and invalid passwords.

Thanks everyone for your help